# How to run the seed.js, given in the generator-angular-fullstack, on OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, openshift, mean

I'm developing an app, using MEAN.js and its generator (https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack), and Openshift as a hosting.

The project template of the generator includes a script (*server/config/seed.js*) to populate the database with two users.

In localhost, it is called automatically, but I also can call it using `node server/config/seed.js` (suppose you're on the root app directory).

The problem is, when I deploy it to Openshift, I run it and no error is reported, but the mongodb database is not updated. The exactly steps I do to run it on Openshift are:

- Connect to ssh: `ssh ....`
- `cd app-root/runtime/repo/`
- `node server/config/seed.js``

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few options:
in server/config/production.js add

```
seedDB: true
```

or change **NODE_ENV** to development coz during 1st deployment it is set to production

then

```
grunt
grunt:buildcontrol:openshift
```

should be working now